# Module '"faker"' can only be default-imported using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag error after using npm i faker

Tags: angular, faker

I am new in Angular. I installed `faker` by using the command `npm i faker`. Now I get the message

```
Module '"faker"' can only be default-imported using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flagts(1259)
index.d.ts(395, 5): This module is declared with using 'export =', and can only be used with a default import when using the 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' flag
```

The app structure is node_modules faker index.js

In index.js I have

```
// since we are requiring the top level of faker, load all locales by default
var Faker = require('./lib');
var faker = new Faker({ locales: require('./lib/locales') });
module['exports'] = faker;
```

I would really appreciate any suggestion or answer

Answer (score 3):

Just use:

```js
import * as faker from "faker";
```

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)